# How to call method in class throw event?

Tags: javascript

I have an element that need to drag in window, code with function work well, but when i use classes i cant understand why it doesnt.

Can you help me with `manipulate_this_element()` method in codepen below?

https://codepen.io/igor-sushko/pen/oNNBvQX?editors=1011

```
class View {
  create_staff() {
    console.log("staff work!");
    this.listener();
  };

  listener() {
    console.log("listener work!");
    let a = document.getElementById("AAA");
    a.addEventListener("mousedown", this.mouse_down)
    // .onmousedown = this.mouse_down();
  };

  mouse_down(e) {
    let that = this;
    console.log("mouse_down work!");
    e.preventDefault();
    document.addEventListener("mousemove",  that.manipulate_this_element)
    // document.onmousemove = this.manipulate_this_element();
  };

  manipulate_this_element() {
    console.log("manipulate_this_element work!");
  };
}

let a = new View();
a.create_staff();
```

I want to see "manipulate_this_element work!" in console when i moving mouse

Comment: Side Note: You don't put `;` after methods in `class` syntax. They're *tolerated*, but unnecessary.

Comment: Another side note: adding event listeners without removing them will lead you into undesired results.

Comment: Thanks for comments, i know that, but for more clean example i cut all other methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that with `a.addEventListener("mousedown", this.mouse_down)` the `mouse_down` would not be called on the view object when the event occurs, so the `this` within that `mouse_down` does not refer to the view instance anymore.

To solve the problem you have various ways to bind the `this` to the function.

Given that you already use `class` then you are probably already able to use this syntax:

```
 mouse_down = (e) => {
 }
```

Using the arrow function that way will bind the `this` of that arrow function to the instance of `View`.

The big advantage of this method is, that this also allows you to remove the event listener easily using `a.removeEventListener("mousedown", this.mouse_down)`

Here the full code:

```
class View {
  create_staff() {
    console.log("staff work!");
    this.listener();
  }

  listener() {
    console.log("listener work!");
    let a = document.getElementById("AAA");
    a.addEventListener("mousedown", this.mouse_down)
    // .onmousedown = this.mouse_down();
  }

  mouse_down = (e) => {
    let that = this;
    console.log("mouse_down work!");
    e.preventDefault();
    document.addEventListener("mousemove",  that.manipulate_this_element)
    // document.onmousemove = this.manipulate_this_element();
  }

  manipulate_this_element = () => {
    console.log("manipulate_this_element work!");
  }
}

let a = new View();
a.create_staff();
```

Comment: It's working! Thank you wery mach :)

Comment: `mouse_down = (e) =>`  You must now this is ecma 6. @IgorSushko

Comment: @NikolaLukic Not ES6. Class fields are still a proposal (currently for ES10) only.

Answer (score 0):

It is too late for :

```
    mouse_down(e) {

      let that = this;
      ...

    }
```

In mouse event callback 'this' is undefined.

Most simply but not the best way is to use global scope access.

```
listener() {
    var root = this;
    console.log("listener work!");
    let a = document.getElementById("AAA");
    a.addEventListener("mousedown", this.mouse_down)

    // Global access 
    document.addEventListener("mousemove",  a.manipulate_this_element, false);

   // simple this
    document.addEventListener("mousemove",  root.manipulate_this_element, false);

  };


 mouse_down(e) {
    let that = this;
    console.log("mouse_down work!");
    e.preventDefault();
    // You can't attach event infinity , just one time.
  };
```